# How to discover the java identifier of an Android application

Tags: android

An example will be the simplest way to explain what I need.
I have Total Commander installed on my phone. I discovered in the /data/data directory, a subdirectory named :
com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander
This is exactly what I am trying to find for the other applications.
I don't know the proper name for this identifier.

For example, I have the "Horloge" app installed. How can I find the corresponding identifier (which is probably the Java identifier or the app) ?

The reason of the question : the MDM which handles this device needs this identifier to allow the app.
Note that in /data/data I have nothing else than the already mentioned subdirectory.
The device is not rooted, and I do not intend to root it.
My question is not for this specific device (Nexus 5) but generally in Android.

**Update**
I already found a way for some apps :

- Opening Total Commander
- Select a file (example text file)
- Select "open with"
- A second time select "open with" in the page which has
  opened
- I get a list of all applications able to open the file, and the identifier is indicated for all of them.

Another possibility :
in /storage/emulated/O/Android/data  a lot of applications have their identifier shown.

This does not solve the problem for an application like "Horloge" which has no associated file and is not in the list of Android/data

Answer (score 0):

The final answer is simple : there is an application which shows this name :
Package Name Viewer